# GUI object out of position and alignment at Run

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I was developing an iPhone application. I did simple drag and drop to add these features but the when I run the application the position of objects in simulator is random.

Help!

[image: GUI Layout in my StoryBoard]

[image: Output in my SImulator]

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar problem, I just simple unchecked an option 'use autolayout'. You can find that option as under

.xib file -> interface builder document -> use autolayout.